# Swift: How to validate Social Security Number (SSN)?

Tags: ios, swift, regex

How can I validate that a `String` encodes a valid American Social Security Number (SSN), with a pattern like `123-45-6789`, using Swift?

Validate means to check if the given string matches a pattern `123-45-6789`.

Comment: There really is no reason for the immediate down + close vote, right?

Comment: Just looked this up, and learned that SSN doesn't have a check digit. Lol, what a joke.

Comment: @Alexander My attempt is in the answer. do you still think it still should be downvoted? I just think that this question might be commonly asked that's why I did QA which is also appreciated by StackOverflow. tbh I don't understand what's the problem.

Comment: @TungFam Oh I didn't notice that. I'll reverse my vote.

Comment: FYI - self answered questions still need to fully comply with the standards of SO. This question shows no effort, no research, and it's unclear what exact coding issue the question is struggling with. The question needs to be written as well as any other question so it can be answered by anyone, not just the author of the question.

Comment: Without specifying the relevant country, it is either unanswerable or too broad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Simply:**

Step1. create a method:

```
func isValidSsn(_ ssn: String) -> Bool {
  let ssnRegext = "^(?!(000|666|9))\\d{3}-(?!00)\\d{2}-(?!0000)\\d{4}$"
  return ssn.range(of: ssnRegext, options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
}
```

Step2. Use it:

```
let ssn = "123-45-6789"
validateSsn(ssn) // true
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Adding an extension to String is a really, really heavy-handed way of solving this problem.

Comment: I think you can take it out of the extension if it doesn't work for you. @tadman

Comment: I like that you've given a solution but if people don't understand the implications of it this could cause a lot of problems. Why can't this be a simple Swift method that takes a string argument?

Comment: agree on that. thanks. editing

Comment: @tadman edited. thanks for a comment

Comment: Now that's much more easily understood.

Comment: `validateSsn` is better as `isValidSSN(ssn)`. Consider the call side: `if validateSsn(ssn)` vs `if isValidSSN(ssn) { ... `

Comment: I agree that this version is more easily understood, but there's no reason an extension on String has to be "heavy handed". If it were up to me, I would probably add a `func isValidSSN() -> Bool` in a `private extension String`.

Comment: It's even better to make a custom type that ensures its valid at initialization (failable initializer), and maintains that invariant thereafter

Comment: @Alexander agree on that. edited!

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use a custom type for this. It has a failable initializer that you use to initialize it from a String. Once you have an non-nil instance of an SSN, you know that it's a valid SSN, and you never need to check again.

I'm parsing the SSN into a `UInt32`, and serializing it back to a String whenever necessary. This prevents ARC and heap storage overhead associated with allocating and passing around strings. Here's the implementation:

```
import Foundation

struct SSN {
    // Stores aaa-bb-ccc as aaabbbccc
    let ssn: UInt32

    init?(_ string: String) {
        let segments = string.split(separator: "-")

        guard segments.lazy.map({ $0.count }) == [3, 2, 3] else {
            debugPrint("SSN segments must be lenght 3, 2, 3 (e.g. 123-45-678).")
            return nil
        }


        guard !zip(segments, ["000", "00", "000"]).contains(where: {$0.0 == $0.1}) else {
            debugPrint("SSN segments cannot be all zeros.")
            return nil
        }

        let firstSegment = segments[0]
        guard firstSegment != "666", !firstSegment.hasPrefix("9") else {
            debugPrint("The first SSN segment (\(firstSegment)) cannot be 666, or be in the range 900-999.")
            return nil
        }
        let dashesRemoved = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")

        self.ssn = UInt32(dashesRemoved)!
    }
}

extension SSN: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    init(stringLiteral literalString: String) {
        self.init(literalString)!
    }
}

extension SSN: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()

        formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 3
        let segment1 = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: self.ssn / 100000))!


        formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2
        let segment2 = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: (self.ssn / 1000) % 100))!

        formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 3
        let segment3 = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: self.ssn % 1000))!
        return "\(segment1)-\(segment2)-\(segment3)"
    }
}
```

And some tests:

```
let testSSNString = "123-45-678"
let optionalTestSSN = SSN(testSSNString)

guard let testSSN = optionalTestSSN else {
    assertionFailure("Valid SSN (\(testSSNString)) wasn't successfully parsed.")
    fatalError()
}

assert(testSSN.description == testSSNString, "SSN (\(testSSN)) was not correctly converted back to String.")

func assertSSNShouldBeNil(_ string: String, because reason: String) {
    assert(SSN(string) == nil, reason + " should be nil.")
}


assertSSNShouldBeNil("123-45-678-9",    because: "SSN with too many segment")
assertSSNShouldBeNil("123-45",          because: "SSN with too few segments")
assertSSNShouldBeNil("",                because: "Empty SSN")


assertSSNShouldBeNil("000-12-345",      because: "SSN with all-zero segment 1")
assertSSNShouldBeNil("123-00-456",      because: "SSN with all-zero segment 2")
assertSSNShouldBeNil("123-45-000",      because: "SSN with all-zero segment 3")

assertSSNShouldBeNil("666-12-345",      because: "SSN starting with 666")
assertSSNShouldBeNil("900-12-345",      because: "SSN starting with number in range 900-999")
assertSSNShouldBeNil("999-12-345",      because: "SSN starting with number in range 900-999")
```